# Get the value of a variable and array outside a self-invoking function

Tags: javascript, function

I have a self invoking function in javascript and I have another function in the same file where I need the value of a variable that is inside the self-invoking function. How can I do that?

Edit: So I can get one variable, but how about more variables or an array?
And I also have a semicolon at the beggining, how to deal with it:
;(function() {
...
})();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple define the variable not in the function but before:

```
var a = 1;
(function(){ /* do stuff and use a*/})();

function(){
    // use a again
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it as part of the return. Depending upon your exact pattern it could go like

```
var app =(function(){

    var x = 5;

    function app() {

    }

    app.x = x;

    return app;

})();
```

Comment: Why is `app` being defined as a function in this example? Why not just an object? (E.g. `return {x: x};`

Comment: Because, using this pattern, app is the constructor. Hence, "depending upon your exact pattern".

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = (function(y) { return y + 2; })(2);
alert(x);
```

Works  just like this:

```
function addTwo(y) { return y + 2; }
x = addTwo(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your self invoking func
(function(){
    var getStuff = holdsStuff();  
    console.log(getStuff.a); //getStuff.b, getStuff.cArr etc;
})();

//func in same file that holds the vars that you need.
function holdsStuff(){
    var a = 10;
    var b = 15;
    var cArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
    return { a: a, b: b, cArr: cArr};
}
```